# Illegal state from Sonar when scanning sprint boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube

This is a very strange issue, it looks like Sonar which we have integrated into our CI/CD is throwing an exception every other build. NOT every build. But can find no other reports or source that would explain why. Is this a bug in Sonar? OR is it a problem in my code?

```
Analyzing 13059 functions to detect bugs.
Failed to analyze xxx.xxxx.xxx.SomeService#someMethod(Lroot/to/Class;ILjava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;Ljava/util/Set;Lroot/to/another/class;)Ljava/util/Optional; due to an exception; skipping.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible type constraints were ANDed - this should be impossible because the corresponding paths should be eliminated
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.G.C$_B.A(na:874)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.B.F.A(na:2546)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.R.C(na:297)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:3143)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:1340)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:920)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:12)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.E(na:2983)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:932)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.B(na:3509)
    at com.sonarsource.A.A.V.A(na:1908)
    at com.sonarsource.A.C.executeChecksOnFunction(na:479)
    at com.sonarsource.A.C.executeChecks(na:1032)
    at com.sonarsource.A.C.execute(na:3562)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:62)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:64)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
```

Comment: _"Incompatible type constraints were ANDed - this should be impossible ..."_  - Looks like you should submit a [bug report](https://community.sonarsource.com/).

Comment: done, hopefully they can advise how to mitigate if it is a bug.